# "Waiting to attach to [app name] on [device name]" message in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

For some reason, when I build my app and run in Xcode, the app will install on my device but it won't launch.

The status bar on top of Xcode says something like:

> Waiting to attach to 'app name' on 'device name'

No console outputs are printed. The app does not launch.

How can I fix this? I need to see console outputs in order to develop properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

This is because you accidentally selected **"Wait for executable to be launched"** in your scheme settings.

Click on your scheme to reveal your schemes and scheme settings.

[image: Scheme]

Click on **Edit Scheme...**, located on the bottom.

[image: "Edit scheme..." option on the bottom]

Select the **Run** option on the left and the **Info** tab on the top.

[image: Scheme options]

Within the **Launch** section, select **Automatically** and save your settings.

[image: Launch settings]

Answer (score 7):

Cause by

Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Info -> Launch automatically